# iphone : SDK disclosure button not response from first TableView to second detail TableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, tableview, disclosure

How can I pass the first tableview row data to second detail view row

I use
`[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];`

or

`cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;`

to show up disclosure button in each cells

it can ,I also add actions in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewaccessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"disclosure button %@ touched",indexPath.row);
```

}

But when I touch the disclosure button I got nothing shows up in console

Than I add actions in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// carry Alarm Name text into sub-table-view to look for detail time and text info
NSLog(@"Alarm Name = %@", [alarmName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
NSLog(@"Index Path Raw# = %i", indexPath.row);

// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
AlarmDetailTableViewController *detailViewController = [[AlarmDetailTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlarmTableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
 detailViewController = nil;
```

}

It can notified on console mode

But I think it always appear the same detail view when I touch any rows in First Level TableView

How to show a new detail view with data from Level one ?

for example

To make the tableView1.row0.text = detail view.title

and show other data under the title

if you need the code I can upload it

my boss said it's not big secret inside...

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand.

Are you asking how to get the `detailViewController`'s title to be the text from a cell you select?

Comment: Oh I think I know how to do this with sample code !
It's Not easy,But I think I can figure out this problem
I read the book from "Beginner Iphone 3 Development"
chapter 9 p.247~267

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is with your:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewaccessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

which should be reading:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

Comment: The devil's in the details. :) I came here looking for a problem of my own; my call was not triggering either... fortunately (or unfortunately) the problem magically has gone away.

Comment: My problem was that I had not set the tableView delegate properly. Do not forget to put <UITableViewDelegate> in the .h - files header.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,if you tapped on accessory button than show another detail view

we need to add a detail view

First create a "`new navigation based application`",ex FirstView

right click on the class folder and choice "`add new File`" choice a new view you wanna display

ex I selected a new tableview named "`DetailView`"

than first go to the DetailView.m go give a section and row numbers

or declare the layout

than back to FirstView.h

add `#import DetailView`

go to FirstView.m

find this method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and use DetailView sub class to create a new view

add the codes like this

```
DetailView *detailView =[[DetailView alloc]init];
detailView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

you can add any view you want to display